# É possível usar um Strings.xml específico para a versão do Android?

Tags: android, android-xml

Eu apliquei uma cor diferente a determinadas palavras dentro de algumas TextViews com a TAG `<font color='#2086F3'></font>`.

Consegui chegar a este resultado depois de uma busca pela internet. O problema é que este recurso só funciona para versões mais atuais do Android, em versões mais antigas a palavra sequer é exibida.

Tentando evitar isto, pensei em fazer uma versão do `strings.xml` para versões mais novas e uma para versões mais antigas do Android.

Seria algo assim:

Versão mais nova `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="txt_fone">Informe seu <font color='#2086F3'>telefone</font> com DDD</string>
<string name="txt_email">Informe seu <font color='#2086F3'>email</font></string>
```

Versão mais antiga `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="txt_fone">Informe seu telefone com DDD</string>
<string name="txt_email">Informe seu email</string>
```

É possível carregar um XML específico para a versão do Android, ou se existir, algum comando ou TAG condicional que opte por um ou outro código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Os strings declarados em ***strings.xml*** são *resources* e tal como qualquer *resource* eles podem ter declarações [alternativas por versão/características do dispositivo](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources).

Crie um novo ***strings.xml*** para a versão(API) a partir da qual quer usar `<font color='#2086F3'></font>`.

Dispositivos com API inferiores usarão o ***strings.xml*** padrão, os com API igual ou superior usarão o novo ***strings.xml***.